# Which time is log timeStamp

Tags: jmeter

I have following test result from load test -

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,Latency
1447675626444,9,API1,201,9
1447675626454,1151,API2,404,Not Found,1151
```

As explicit, call to API2 fails and there is delay of 1oms between two calls. 
I know that label timeStamp is time from epoch but is it the time when request was fired from client or the time when last response byte was received?
If latter then how do I find the time when request was fired from client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `timestamp` is request start time. The `latency` is time from timestamp when the first response byte is received. `elapsed` is time from timestamp when the complete response was received. So in your case,

444: API1 request went out. 9 milliseconds later, at
453: First byte AND last byte of API1 response is received - because latency is the same as elapsed
454: API2 request went out

If you're using a regular thread group in JMeter with two samplers, the second request is not sent out until the response to the first sampler is completely received. Your issue would seem to be something other than pure sequence of calls.

==

To clarify what @Mike said about "request is sent behind two or three lines code.":

The Timestamp is when JMeter sampler code marked the request start event and made a log entry. After which the JVM has to execute a few of lines of code to use Apache HTTPClient object to create a TCP connection, assemble a HTTP request and then send out a HTTP packet over possibly several TCP packets. On any modern system this difference between timestamp and actual request going out will be less than a few millseconds. If this timing is important for you to measure, JMeter isn't really the right tool, you should use a network sniffer like Wireshark to look for timestamp of when the first packet was actually transmitted.

Comment: The issue is application bug uncovered by JMeter :)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the timestamp is the API started time, maybe the request is sent behind two or three lines code. You cannot get the exactly timestamp when request is sent. As far as I know, it doesn't affect your performance.
If you just want to test how long between the request is sent and the response is returned, you need to make another API.

Comment: did not quite get this `maybe the request is sent behind two or three lines code`. timeStamp is important for me since API2 should be called only after API1 got ok, hence in no case API2 should be called before before API1 is completed and is 200 OK

Comment: @Tarun sounds like sequence is important to you, not timestamps.

Comment: yup, I can use if controller to control the behaviour but wanted to figureout what exactly timestamp refers to